# Coldfusion - Update form

Tags: forms, coldfusion, sql-update

Can you advice me please? how to make working form which will allow you insert and update items?
I have one form which works for inserting but in moment when I want to update `<input>` in this form, it returning error with all data which are in form. So I want to ask you for help with updating.

[image]

My code:

Page 1
**Insert part** *(this works)*

```
<cfif isdefined("Form.Name")>

    <cfquery name"something" datasource="#something#>
    INSERT INTO table..
    Values (...)
    </cfquery>

</cfif>
```

**Update part**

```
<cfif isDefined('url.action')>

  <cfquery datasource="Something" name="Something">

    Update table.. 
    SET Name= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Form.Name#"> 
    Where Some_id = '#Form.ID#'

  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

**Page1** **Form**

```
<table>
    <form action="path\Page1.cfm?action=update" method="post">

    <cfloop query="languageField">
      <input name="Name" value="#SomeQuery.Name#">
      <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </cfloop>

    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: What's with the angle brackets in your update query?

Comment: Uf, sorry only mistake.

Comment: What dbms? Rather than 2 operations, you may have the option to do an UPSERT in a single operation and let the database handle if it should INSERT or UPDATE.   Also, rather than `isDefined()`, you should probably use `structkeyexists()` or a Safe Navigation Operator to be a little bit safer.

Answer (score 5):

Your update statement has a missing `#` after the `form.id` variable. You also have single quotes around the value of the `form.id` which will pass in the number as a string. You should also wrap all user generated data with [cfqueryparam](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) tags to protect against SQL Injection attacks.

```
Where Some_id = '#Form.ID'
```

should be

```
Where Some_id = #Form.ID#
```

but should more properly be

```
Where Some_id = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint">
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesnt solving my problem. After updating data in form, I sending all data from forms to one field in SQL instead one value to one field. And I dont know, how to repair ty.

Comment: Hmmm.. what's the actual value of `form.id` on the update page?

Comment: Its primary key from SQL. And I getting all primary keys which are on page but I need to get only one value per row.

Comment: @Jenda My response answered your original question. Your comment is an entirely different situation that needs to be addressed separately. Please create a new question with more details about how your form is structured and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jenda- I meant what's the value of form.id if you output it on the update page? Does it contain a single id or a csv list of numbers, i.e. "2" or "3,5,7"? I suspect it is the latter, due to the structure of your <form>. That is a different issue, but would also cause the error you described because "3,5,7" is not an integer. You should open a new thread, and be sure to include your form - including where you define the "id" field (it is not in your original question, afaict).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have answer.

Query for updating must look like

```
<cfloop list="#form.id#" item="id">

  <cfquery datasource="Something" name="updateform">

    UPDATE table
      SET
      column_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form['Edit_Name_' & id]#" />
      WHERE id = #id#

  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

And into form:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="#query.Name#">

<tr> 
  <td><input name="Edit_Name_#Name#" type="text" value="#query.Name#"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the id value in cfqueryparam, because the current query is vulnerable to sql injection.  Also, though CF does allow the use of the same name in multiple scopes (form.id and variables.id), might consider a different name for the loop index to avoid confusion.